# how to initialize static reference to std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, reference, static, ofstream

I have a class Cl with public member

`static std::ofstream &_rout;`

In main file

```
ofstream out("output.txt");
ofstream& Cl::_rout(out);
```

But I have a compilation error: illegal definition or redefinition.
How can I correct it?

Comment: That [works for me](http://ideone.com/ujN6D). Could you provide a complete example of the code that fails, and the full error message?

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

> Logger.h

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Logger{

    public:
            static void open( const string & logFile);
            static void close();
            // write message
            static void write( const string & message);

    private:
          Logger();
          ofstream fileStream;
          //Logger instance (singleton)
          static Logger instance;
};
```

> Logger.cpp

```
#include "Logger.h"

Logger Logger::instance;

Logger::Logger(){}

void Logger::open( const string& logFile){
   instance.fileStream.open(logFile.c_str());
}
void Logger::close(){
    instance.fileStream.close();

} 
void Logger::write(const string& message){
    ostream& stream =  instance.fileStream ;
    stream << message<< endl;
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "Salida/Logger.h"
int main(){
    Logger::open(path);
    Logger::write("text");
    Logger::close();
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can only set the reference at the static/global scope

```
#include<CL.h>
ofstream& Cl::_rout(out);
int main() {
  // ...
}
```

It is not possible to re-set a reference after it was declared (and initialized).  You could achieve what you are after by using pointers instead of references:

```
class Cl {
  static std::ofstream* _rout;
};
std::ofstream* CL::_rout = NULL;

int main() {
  ofstream out("output.txt");   
  Cl::_rout = &out;   
}
```

Note that the pointer will be valid only until `out` goes out of scope.  If this is an issue, allocate the memory dynamically:

```
  ofstream* out = new ofstream("output.txt");   
  Cl::_rout = out;
```

And don't forget to `delete` it when you no longer need the object to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Actually if you forget to `delete`, you may not only leak memory, but also a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the following approach:

```
#include <fstream>

class CI
{
public:
  static std::ofstream &_rout;
};

static std::ofstream out("output.txt");

std::ofstream& CI::_rout = out;

int main()
{
}
```

The problem with this, however, is that the name of the output file is fixed (hard-coded into the program).

I suggest that you use a pointer instead of a reference:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>

class CI
{
public:
  static std::ofstream *_rout;
};

std::ofstream* CI::_rout = NULL;

int main()
{
  const char *output_file = "output.txt";
  std::ofstream out(output_file);
  CI::_rout = &out;
}
```